# Magnifying glass cursor

Tags: usability, cursor

I have had a quick look on this site but haven't found anything to help me (unless my search terms were poor). Anyway I came across a post a while back saying that for the cursor on zoom, a magnifying glass with the plus sign inside is the best way to go. However from what I've seen in the past and what I personally find to be the most visually appealing, is with the plus sign to the right of the glass. I was just wondering what your thoughts on this are? Which is better? Or is there an alternative way I'm missing that just dwarfs the first two examples?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question:  I understand why you might have considered this opinion-based (and I thought about closing it too!), but upon reflection I think there is an objective, usability-based approach to answering this question which I have outlined below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Think about what your users need

The magnifying glass is a very well understood idiom for zoom, so it's probably the right cursor to use.

The use of `inset` (plus on the inside) vs `offset` (plus to the right) will depend on the size and use of the cursor.  For example:

- For **large cursors** the `inset` cursor is visually simpler than the `offset` cursor, so option B below is better than A.  For **small cursors**, the plus sign is hard to discern for the `inset` version, so the `offset` cursor is typically used in this situation (i.e. C is better than D):

  [image]
- The `inset` cursor provides better **affordance of precision** for users because it's reasonably clear that the focus of the icon is inside the magnifying glass.  For the `offset` icon, it's unclear where the 'tip' of the icon is.  So for detailed work, the `inset` icon is more suitable:

  [image]

...so by focusing on user needs rather than what is most visually pleasing, you're more likely to arrive at a more usable choice for your app.